# Autoconf : How to get program output in a string and check if another string is present in that

Tags: sh, autotools, autoconf

I am developing a Qt application in Python. It uses a resource file, which needs to be compiled. I am using autotools to manage compilation and installation of my projects.

Now, in order for the resource file to be usable by the application, it needs to be compiled with a certain version of the compilation program (`pyrcc`). I can get the version by putting the output of `pyrcc -version` in a variable in `configure.ac`. But then, I don't know how to check whether the string `pyrcc5` is present in the output. If it is not present, I want to tell the user that his PyRCC programm has the wrong version, and abort `configure`.

Additionally, I would like to avoid the need of an extra variable for the program output, but instead do it like this (Pseudo code):

```py
if "pyrcc5" not in output of "pyrcc -version":
    say "pyrcc has wrong version"
    exit 1
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a `configure.ac` for Autoconf, always remember that you are basically writing a shell script.  Autoconf provides a host of macros that afford you a lot of leverage, but you can usually at least get an idea about basic "How can I do X in Autoconf?" questions by asking instead "How would I do X in a portable shell script?"

In particular, for ...

> I would like to avoid the need of an extra variable for the program
> output, but instead do it like this (Pseudo code):
>
> ```
> if "pyrcc5" not in output of "pyrcc -version":
>     say "pyrcc has wrong version"
>     exit 1
> ```

... the usual tool for a portable shell script to use for such a task is `grep`, and, happily, the easiest way to apply it to the task does not require an intermediate variable.  For example, this implements exactly your pseudocode (without emitting any extraneous messaging to the console):

```
if ! pyrcc -version | grep pyrcc5 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "pyrcc has wrong version"
  exit 1
fi
```

That pipes the output of `pyrcc -version` into `grep`, and relies on the fact that `grep` exits with a success status if and only if it finds any matches.

You could, in fact, put exactly that in your `configure.ac`, but it would be more idiomatic to

- Use the usual Autoconf mechanisms to locate `pyrcc` and `grep`, and to use the versions discovered that way;
- Use the Autoconf `AS_IF` macro to write the `if` construct, instead of writing it literally;
- Use standard Autoconf mechanisms for emitting a "checking..." message and reporting on its result; and
- Use the standard Autoconf mechanism for outputting a failure message and terminating.

Of course, all of that makes the above considerably more complex, but also more flexible and portable.  It might look like this:

```
AC_ARG_VAR([PYRCC], [The name or full path of pyrcc. Version 5 is required.])

# ...

AC_PROG_GREP
AC_CHECK_PROGS([PYRCC], [pyrcc5 pyrcc], [])
AS_IF([test "x${PYRCC}" = x],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([Required program pyrcc was not found])])

# ...

AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether ${PYRCC} has an appropriate version])
AS_IF([! pyrcc -version | grep pyrcc5 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
  AC_MSG_ERROR([pyrcc version 5 is required, but ${PYRCC} is a different version])
], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
])
```

In addition to portability and conventional Autoconf progress messaging, that also gets the builder a way to specify a particular `pyrcc` executable to `configure` (by setting variable `PYRCC` in its environment), documents that in `configure`'s help text, and exports `PYRCC` as a `make` variable.

Oh, and I snuck in a check for `pyrcc` under the name `pyrcc5`, too, though I don't know whether that's useful in practice.

The final result no longer looks much like the shell script fragment I offered first, I grant. But again, the pure shell script fragment could be used as is, and also, the fully Autoconfiscated version is derived directly from the pure script.

Comment: "I snuck in a check for pyrcc" - that's just right, I was intending to check for both anyways ! And thanks for the AutoConf code ! ;)